# awk select and sum value from multiple columns based on delimiter

Tags: bash, awk, vcf-vcard

I have a big file (vcf) with millions of rows and ~400 tab delimited columns. A row with few number of columns for brevity is pasted below:

```
1/1:0,0,0:0:0,0,0,0    1/1:0,0,0:0:0,0,0,0     1/1:37,3,0:1:0,0,1,0    1/1:0,0,0:0:0,0,0,0
```

I would like to split each column with the delimiter `:` and print the fourth set of values (0,0,0,0 for col 1; 0,0,0,0 for col 2; 0,0,1,0 for col 3; and so on) for each column.

So, desired output is:

```
Col1      Col2        Col3      Col4      ..   Coln
0,0,0,0   0,0,0,0     0,0,1,0   0,0,0,0   ..   a,b,c,d
```

Is this too crazy to handle for awk?  I'd prefer to do this in awk as my file is in our unix server. I can do it in R, though I can imagine it taking a lot of time to read the file, split each column, and process, etc. So I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Optional: to make this tougher, can the first two numbers of the four values be summed and the last two of the four values be summed to get a value1,value2 column? Maybe I am asking too much. Sorry. In this case, following would be the desired output:

```
Col1  Col2    Col3  Col4  ..   Coln 
0,0   0,0     0,1   0,0   ..   a+b,c+d
```

Comment: _starting from column 10_ -  why do I have to scroll away the first 9 cols to see the beef? Please, just post the needed parts as input and the desired output.

Comment: @JamesBrown good point. edited for clarity. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
          {sub(/.*:/,"",$i); 
           split($i,a,","); 
           $i=a[1]+a[2] "," a[3]+a[4]}}1' file


0,0 0,0 0,1 0,0
```

adding column headers is not that hard either...

set `-v OFS='\t'` for tab separated output fields.

Comment: Thank you yet again for the rescue! Works great. Could you please explain the second line `{sub(/.*:/,"",$i);` so I can implement similar tasks on my own in the future? Thanks.

Comment: got it. for all columns, replace anything up till `:` with nothing. then the third line stores that into array a. the last line retrieves the elements of each array and sums them.

Comment: correct, since regex is greedy it replaces until the last colon, split the last element and add up the corresponding elements, overwrite existing fields so that printing can be delegated back.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{
        for(i=1;i<=NF*2;i+=2){           #print first line because one column is become two column so NF*2
            printf "val"i"\tval"i+1"\t"
        }
        print "";
      } 
     {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        match($i,".*(.,.),(.,.)$",a);    #match function matches  first two numbers of the four values 
        printf a[1]"\t"a[2]"\t";         #and the last two of the four values
    }
    print "";
    }' file
```